# Diffusion on a Boundaryless Manifold and Tesselation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, finite-element-method

Suppose we are dealing with diffusion on a boundaryless manifold $M$. When people use the finite-element method to find an approximate solution, I always see them use
\begin{align}
\int_{M^*} W \Delta U \mathrm{d} x & = - \int_{M^*} \nabla W \cdot \nabla U \mathrm{d} x,
\end{align}
in the weak form. Here $\Delta$ is the Beltrami-operator and $\nabla$ is the surface gradient, $M^*$ is usually a triangularly tesselated approximation of $M$, meaning locally planar. I was wondering if the usage of above formula (which is essentially product rule + divergence theorem) is actually valid in this case since $M^*$ is not a smooth object, meaning that it contains `kinks' in the transition form one triangle to the other. Or should the replacement $M \rightarrow M^*$ be regarded as part of the discretization ?

Comment: The short answer is "I don't know", but in case it's helpful, a triangulated surface is locally Euclidean away from the _vertices_ (where the curvature is equal to the angular defect times a delta function). That is, there's no intrinsic kink along the edges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe that the problem is that in the derivation of above identity, one implicitly assumes that the contribution of the boundary integral over one triangle is cancelled by the contribution of the same edges that belong to other triangles. I don't believe this to be true since the normal vectors on either side of the edge are not each other's opposites (unlike in a smooth manifold). Could this be true ?